# Google api for c# reading empty Google sheet cell cause out of bound exception

Tags: c#, google-api

I am trying to load Google sheet data using SSIS script component.

Here is the Google sheet:

[image]

Here is the script in SSIS component (type of source) to read the sheet

```
        using System;
        using System.Data;
        using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper;
        using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper;
        using Google.GData;
        using Google.GData.Client;
        using Google.GData.Extensions;
        using Google.GData.Spreadsheets;

        [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute]
        public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
        {

            public override void PreExecute()
            {
                base.PreExecute();
            }

            public override void PostExecute()
            {
                base.PostExecute();

            }

            public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
            {
                //Create new Spreadsheet service

                SpreadsheetsService GoogleExcelService;
                GoogleExcelService = new SpreadsheetsService("Spreadsheet-Vikash-Test-App");
                //Connect with Google Spreadsheet services using Google account credentials
                GoogleExcelService.setUserCredentials("xxxx@gmail.com", "somepassword");

                //Create a new Spreadsheet Query
                SpreadsheetQuery query = new SpreadsheetQuery();
                //Pass the SpreadsheetQuery to Spreadsheet Feed
                SpreadsheetFeed myFeed = GoogleExcelService.Query(query);

                //The Spreadsheet Feed connects with Googel Spreadsheet services and returns feed. Each Feed represents one Google Spreadsheet.

                foreach (SpreadsheetEntry mySpread in myFeed.Entries)
                {
                    //Run the code logic if the Spreadsheet name is ProductDetails
                    if (mySpread.Title.Text == "testForSSIS")
                    {

                        WorksheetFeed wfeed = mySpread.Worksheets;
                        foreach (WorksheetEntry wsheet in wfeed.Entries)
                        {
                            //Run the code logic if worksheet name is Sheet1
                            if (wsheet.Title.Text == "Sheet1")
                            {

                                AtomLink atm = wsheet.Links.FindService(GDataSpreadsheetsNameTable.ListRel, null);

                                ListQuery Lquery = new ListQuery(atm.HRef.ToString());

                                ListFeed LFeed = GoogleExcelService.Query(Lquery);

                                //Each ListFeed represents a row so naviage through each listfeed and add them into Output Buffer.
                                foreach (ListEntry LmySpread in LFeed.Entries)
                                {
                                    Output0Buffer.AddRow();
                                    //Output0Buffer.strProduct = LmySpread.Elements[0].Value;
                                    //Output0Buffer.intQuantity = LmySpread.Elements[1].Value;

                                    Output0Buffer.AgeName = LmySpread.Elements[0].Value;
                                    Output0Buffer.LowerBound = Int32.Parse(LmySpread.Elements[1].Value);
                                    Output0Buffer.UpperBound = Int32.Parse(LmySpread.Elements[2].Value);


                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

        }
```

I am no c# programmer but a BI developer using a little bit script here and there. But I guess you can probably run it independently without SSIS.

So the problem is for example I remove the 40 under Upperbound so that cell is empty. The script will report index out of bound exception. I have done some debugging and found when that cell is empty the row now just contains 2 elements, so this line will generate the error because now LmySpread.Elements[2] does not exist.

```
                                    Output0Buffer.UpperBound = Int32.Parse(LmySpread.Elements[2].Value);
```

I guess this is more of Google API than C# question. I am not sure if there is way to specify how many elements to read etc.

Comment: Are you able to login at all?  all I get is invalid credentials on setUserCredentials.

Comment: I substituted credentials of course, you can use your google account to do the test.

Comment: What credentials are you substituting? I would love to see this working

Comment: Sorry that's personal account, so can't share. You can register an google account or probably you already got one. Then you can use Google sheet to create an example sheet. The name of the file and sheet used will be used in the code (testForSSIS and Sheet1 in the code above).

Comment: Are you creating Oauth2 credentials? Are you using a api key from dev console? I don't understand what you are calling credentials.

Comment: That's just a username and password for your Google account.

Comment: There isn't a Oauth2 option for this? I thought all of the client login stuff was getting shut down.

Answer (score 2):

```
Output0Buffer.AgeName = LmySpread.Elements[0].Value;
if (LmySpread.Elements.Length >= 2)
{
    Output0Buffer.LowerBound = Int32.Parse(LmySpread.Elements[1].Value);
}
if (LmySpread.Elements.Length >= 3)
{
    Output0Buffer.UpperBound = Int32.Parse(LmySpread.Elements[2].Value);
}
```

Just check the number of elements in the row, and don't access the ones that aren't there!

Comment: Tried yours got this error: Error 2 'Google.GData.Spreadsheets.ListEntry.CustomElementCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Length' and no extension method 'Length' accepting a first argument of type 'Google.GData.Spreadsheets.ListEntry.CustomElementCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\2\Vsta\SSIS_SC110\VstaflrbHAXpKUGegwue3A__xpQ\Vsta81JtszC__dEa5uQYiiT4qYw\main.cs 68 64 SC_20fb5bc1ce3044368f49fd5a512c9d2d

Comment: Try .Count instead of .Length instead.

Comment: Although that works but if there is empty cell in the middle, e.g. LowerBound then LowerBound will take the value of UpperBound. I think this method will never know which column is empty.

Comment: You are just going to have to have code that copes with gaps etc.  You can use Int32.TryParse (it has different parameters) which will not throw errors if the element isn't an int. You can check that Elements[x].Value != null before you try to convert.

Comment: You can't know which one is Elements[x] . E.g. Elements[1 can be either lowerBound (when lowerBound is not empty) or uppperBound (when lowerBound is empty but upperbound is not empty).